# Hash getter and setter on ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord object that was serializing a hash property to one of my database columns. I'd like to get away from this since querying by one of the hash keys is very difficult/not clean. So I've split all the keys of the hash up into separate properties on the model. However, I have a lot of places using this code so in the meantime while I convert everything I'd like to have a property on my ActiveRecord object that is for Rails only (i.e. it doesn't populate back to my database) that wraps up those properties into a hash like it used to be and allows values to be set and get.

So for instance, this is what I used to have:

```
class MyCls < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :state, Hash
    attr_accessible :id, :mode
```

I'm getting rid of `:state` and replace it with 7 different values that made up this hash. But I'd still like to be able to access those values like this: `MyObj.state[:obj_num]`. Even though I now have `obj_num` as a property (i.e. `MyObj.obj_num`). I'm thinking the best way to do this would be to have a `state` property with a getter and a setter, but I can't quite seem to get the syntax right. For the setter I'd need to support both setting the hash as a whole and setting individual keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to say: I dont think thats the best solution. When you touch this code again in lets say 3 years it will be like "WHAAAAAT HAVE I DONE?"... It whould the best solution to replace all the snippets in your code with other code.

You can prepend the `method_missing` method of the object after removing this line `serialize :state` to fetch all calls that want to access the not anymore existing serialized field of the object. Its explained here:

http://blog.enriquez.me/2010/2/21/dont-forget-about-respond-to-when-implementing-method-missing/

Its called metaprogramming. Thats the "rails magic" that makes all the `find_by_attribute_name` stuff working without defining each of these methods. Can be cool stuff but you need to be very carefull and you need to know what your doing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess I couldn't hide the fact that I'm newer to Ruby/Rails development :)

Comment: I wouldnt have guessed that. Metaprogramming isn't easy and not well known here although a huge amount of the rails default functionality is based on stuff like this.